# How to get the widget value into source code of any wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am working with the WordPress and I am using text widget. and I am using this line of code it working well.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
    <div class="rightside" role="complementary">

    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>

    </div>
<?php endif;  ?>
```

Actually my requirement is I just want the widget value into source code like

```
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="rightside" role="complementary">

            <?php 
                      **$x= dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); 

                      echo $x;**
                ?>
            </div>

   <?php endif;  ?>
```

How can I get the all content of widget into the source code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function below (paste it into your functions.php):

```
if(!function_exists('get_dynamic_sidebar')) {
    
    function get_dynamic_sidebar($index = 1) {
        $sidebar_contents = "";
        ob_start();
        dynamic_sidebar($index);
        $sidebar_contents = ob_get_clean();
  
        return $sidebar_contents;
    }
}
```

So your code will look like:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>

<div class="rightside" role="complementary">
    <?php 
        $x= get_dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); 

        echo $x;
    ?>
</div>

<?php endif;  ?>
```